# Alternate Row colors for a particular row class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and am trying to alternate the row colors for 1 particular tr class

```
<tr class="found">
```

The jquery below changes the row color for all table row.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.odd {background: #caf2fe;}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
 }); 
</script>
```

I have data coming in from my database and have 2 different tables on the form so only want one specific row called found to have this Zebra pattern.

Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your selector more specific.

```
$("tr.found:odd").addClass("odd");
```

Adding `.found` selects only those odd `tr`s that have class `found`

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/4bmMJ/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("tr.found:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Using nth-child is unnecessary and does not solve the problem, which is to apply the class only to odd rows *of a specific class* i.e. `found`.

Comment: @Asad: ah yes I missed the `.found` class, have added that in. Yes nth-child is more characters but still works ok, the :odd selector works too.